# Binding to the actual of a UserControl in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, storyboard

Seen some questions on SO but none answers my question.

What I want to accomplish: 
I have a custom control (lets call it A) which moves around the canvas using a storyboard. And I want to bind another custom control's canvas (lets call it B) position onto the first control.

Using the TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual) I can get the actual position of control A, but I can't figure out how to get a binding to B's Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top on this.

Has anyone figured out how to accomplish this task? Or get me pointed into the right direction?

Comment: Are control A and/or B custom controls or standard controls?

Comment: In this case both control A and B are custom controls.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you move the position of control A by updating its Canvas.Left and Canvas.Right properties? If this is the case, you do not need to use TransformToVisual, you can just bind their Canvas Top & Left properties together:

```
<Canvas >
  <TextBlock x:Name="ControlB"
             Text="Some Text"
             FontSize="15"
             Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=ControlA, Path=(Canvas.Left)}"
             Canvas.Top="{Binding ElementName=ControlA, Path=(Canvas.Top)}"/>
  <TextBlock x:Name="ControlA"
             Text="Some Text"
             FontSize="13"
             Canvas.Left="100"
             Canvas.Top="100"/>    
</Canvas>
```

Regards,
Colin E.

Comment: Nope, like I've mentioned in the question Control A is moved using a storyboard

Comment: Sure.. but the storyboard must be modifying some properties of the control in order to move it? In my above example, ut doesn't matter what changes the properties of ControlA, a XAML value, code behind value, binding or a storyboard - ControlB will always follow.